# 8-month avocado plant developed large spots on leaves that are spreading... what do I do?

Tags: houseplants, avocado

[image]I have an ~8 month avocado plant that was growing really well until about two months ago, when it started developing large dark brown spots on the leafs. The spots continued to spread to the neighboring leafs (started at the bottom leafs and have moved up), until the entire leaf browns and dries up, at which time I remove. At one point the plant was also drooping, but water seemed to help that. I also moved the plant into a larger pot, and have been spraying some fertilizer on it but it seems to be progressing, with the leaves turning brown and curling on the ends. I moved the plant to a sunnier spot a couple of days ago, but it does still get cold in the house. Any suggestions on how to proceed to prevent my plant from dying? :( Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Hi what is the lowest temperature it recieve? as it could be cold damage or something else

Comment: Please post some pictures.   Do not continue to fertilise.  I am sure the fertiliser you bought has direction on the box/bottle.  Make sure you do not use any more and any more often than is recommended for an indoor plants.   If it is winter where you are you should not add any fertiliser until spring.

Comment: Hello, I added a photo, and the temperature indoor fluctuates between 60 and 70 with low humidity. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Avocado plants tend to get brown leaves for lots of different reasons

Normally when flowering it would use the mobile nutrients that it requires from the leaves. Leading to dead leaves that are brown and dry as you describe.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=R33ifj7JqgI

but judging from your post it may be due to cold weather or chlorine in the water.

Update: may be chloramin buildup in the potting medium.

I doubt it's too much ultraviolet light as it is indoors

3 reasons why leaves turn brown  (Avocado style) https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eM7xOUcL_F0

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input! My plant isn't very large at this point and it hasn't had any mature flowering, but based on the second video you sent possibly it's the chlorine? We drink our tap water here but it is quite hard, so I did try flushing the plant with purified water and figured I would do so once a week.. do you think this is the right thing to do?

Comment: Defo stop using tap water if it's hard, the water I have from the tap is "hard" and I found that it literally hurts the plants all the time p it's very concerning  I can only use bottled water at PH6.2